# Getting $P(B) = 0$ by combining conditional probability formula with mutual exclusivity

Tags: probability

**What mistake have I made here to get $P(B) = 0$?**

Say that two events, $A$ and $B$, are mutually exclusive, then $P(A|B) = 0$ and $P(A \cap B) = 0$. If write out the conditional probability formula (and sub in the aforementioned conditional and join probabilities):

$$P(A|B) = P(A \cap B) / P(B)$$
$$0 = 0 / P(B)$$

Then I can rearrange it to say:

$$P(B) = 0 / 0$$

Which is immediately suspect, because I know that $P(B)$ could be non-zero.

Comment: The problem is that $0/0$ is undetermined. What is happening is that the data you provided is not enough to compute the value of $P(B)$.

Comment: Your statement has nothing to do when it comes to the value of $P(B)$

Comment: "Divide by zero" error doesn't indicate an electronic fault.  You ought not divide by zero if you want a sensible result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is twofold in your derivation:

- First, $0/0$ is obviously a nonsense expression. That should be the first key that something is wrong, that there's a division by zero. This expression evaluates to neither $1$ nor $0$ - it is simply undefined, and there are multiple ways to rigorously prove this (but it's beyond the scope of this post).
- Secondly, you have $0 = 0/P(B)$. Immediately you conclude that $0=0$ by simplifying.

What this entails is this: the value of $P(B)$ is altogether irrelevant. If $A,B$ are mutually exclusive, in this formula, it doesn't even matter what the probability of $B$ is, $P(A|B)=0$ regardless of $P(B)$.

It might be noteworthy to keep in mind that $P(A|B)=0$ is more a "corollary" of the definition of mutually exclusive, than is $P(A \cap B)=0$. You could argue it this way without applying both at the same time: by definition, mutually exclusive events have no intersection, and therefore $P(A \cap B) =0$. Therefore, from the formula for conditional probability,

$$P(A | B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}  = \frac{0}{P(B)} = 0$$

Notice, again, there isn't condition on the value of $P(B)$. The conclusion is simply "it doesn't matter what $P(B)$ is, that $P(A|B)=0$ holds regardless of its value."